# Duplicate questions of very old posts

Tags: support, exact-duplicates, etiquette

I was about to post a question on Superuser, when I found that there was a duplicate of exactly the question I wanted to ask, only it was asked 3 and half years ago with no good answer.

Is it OK for me to ask the question anyway in this situation?

Comment: You can ask a new question, and point out that you have looked at the duplicate (give a link) and say that it doesn't answer your question because [give reasons] ... Alternative is to offer a bounty on the other question.

Comment: If there isn't an answer then it cannot be marked as a duplicate except for a extremely small minority of the community since their isn't an answer with positive reputation.  With that said the proper way to get an answer to the question is to offer a bounty on the existing question

Comment: Also, ensure the old post's tags are correct. Things often seem like a duplicate because of poorly tagged questions, such as the OS version (people just use `windows` instead of `windows-xp` etc). If it turns out the 'dupe' is actually based upon a different version of the OS, it's no longer a dupe.Can you share the link of the 'dupe'?